# Rails: "has already been taken" error on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

The app finds or initializes by an attribute:

```
booking = Booking.where(deal_id: params["id"]).first_or_initialize
```

Then updates some additional attributes

```
    if booking.update!(
        guests: guests,
        names: names,
        time: time)
```

This code gives me the error

```
Validation failed: Deal has already been taken
```

The validation code is

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :deal_id, allow_blank: true, scope: [:experience_id, :time], unless: -> {deal_id.zero? }
```

Why is it giving a "has already been taken" error when first it does first_or_initialize?

Thanks

Comment: Where is pipe drive mentioned in your model?

Comment: corrected it. The error should say deal.

Comment: It means there is a record already present in the DB with same deal and :experience_id, :time .. that is why need booking not getting saved.

Comment: there is a record already present in the DB with same deal and :experience_id, :time, which is the one the code should find when the first_or_initialize is executed. Or am I misunderstanding that method?

Comment: Assuming `first_or_initialize` does what I think it does, then you're looking up a `Booking` by `deal_id` and not finding one, then a new `Booking` is attempted to be created with that `Deal` ID but can't because a `Deal` with that ID already exists in the DB. The first thing that comes to mind is that you may have `Deal` set to `act_as_paranoid` with the `paranoia` gem and that particular `Deal` record has been marked deleted. So it is not found with your initial look-up, but it does exist. If this is the case, you could try `Booking.with_deleted.where(...).first_or_initialize`.

Comment: Bookings are not deleted ever from the db. This app has never used the paranoia gem. A particular Deal record that has been marked deleted is not a possibility

Comment: can you please mention associations between booking, deal, and experience?

Comment: deal is just an attribute of booking.

booking belongs to experience

Comment: What is `time`? Is it current time or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you already have `Booking` with same `deal_id` in scope of `experience_id`, `time`

This could happen if you already had records in the database at the time when you added this uniqueness validation to model

But this is not necessary at all. Your `first_or_initialize` with just `deal_id` doesn't prevent of combination `deal_id`, `experience_id` and time

Besides, it doesn't protect you from race condition

You can check such records count with debug before updating:

```
Booking.where(
  deal_id: booking.deal_id,
  experience_id: booking.experience_id,
  time: time,
).count
```

Comment: It was a race condition

Answer (score 0):

try to run without `update` method without `!` to see where validation has failed

```
result = booking.update(
        guests: guests,
        names: names,
        time: time)
result.errors # <= see related errors here
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# This implies the first record
booking = Booking.find_by(deal_id: params["id"])

if booking.nil?
  booking = Booking.new(
    #... your attributes
  )
else
  # Update the attributes you want
  booking.anything = anything
  ...
end

# This will create / update the record in the database

booking.save!
```

Comment: He wants to get the first record or create a new one.  That replaces the where, but it doesn't create a Booking if there isn't one with that deal_id.